# How to show $F$ is open and $G$ is closed in two-space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $F$ and $G$ be subsets in in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $F=\left \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|x\in[0,10], y \geq\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right \}$ and 
 $G= \left \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|y>\frac{1}{1+x^2} \right \}$

Show that F is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that $G$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

---

I'm really uncertain how to prove it. I know a set is open if every point in the set has a neighborhood lying in the set. I also know that a set is closed if the complement is open.

Comment: Show F is the intersection of the inverse images of two closed sets by two continuous functions.  Show G is the inverse image of an  open set by a continuous function.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure why that means that the sets are closed and open, and I would also be back at my question regarding showing sets are open or closed.

Comment: Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Then: $f$ is continuous $\iff$ for every open set $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ the preimage $f^{-1}[G]$ is open $\iff$ for every closed set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ the preimage $f^{-1}[F]$ is closed. Do you know this fact?

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $f(x,y) = y - \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

But then $F = ([0,1]\times \mathbb{R}) \cap f^{-1}[[0,\infty)$ is closed as the intersection of two closed sets (inverse image of closed set under $f$ is closed)

and $G = f^{-1}[(0,\infty)]$ is open (inverse image under $f$ of an open set of the reals.